# Make [race] a synonym of [demographics]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[racism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racism) and [race](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race). They're not quite the same thing, but I'm seeing some tag confusion already. [This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/56078/why-is-it-considered-racist-to-say-white-lives-matter) was tagged [race], when it needed to be tagged [racism]. Fixed it, but the remaining usages of [race](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/race) all seem like they could be rolled into [demographics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demographics), which would avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I agree - I actually [proposed](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/demographics/synonyms) the synonym a couple of months ago, but as yet no one seems to have voted on it. Embarrassingly, I also made the tagging error on the question you're referring to!

Comment: @CDJB Yeah, tag synonyms for the masses is kinda a joke. I can't even vote on your synonym proposal (and I doubt most people who could would ever visit the page to do so). Faster to suggest a mod do this via Meta. And we've all made tagging mistakes sooner or later. I could see how easy this one would be to make

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There don't seem to be any objections, and it seems sensible to me, so I went ahead and created the synonym.

Answer (score -2):

These tags should not be combined.

Race refers to matters either pertaining to, or believed rightly or wrongly to pertain to, genes and ethnicity -- usually irrespective of age, sex, income, or vital statistics.

Whereas demographics deals with vital statistics, and data about varying subsets of populations chiefly of interest to marketers, insurers, industrial designers and engineers, administrators, and legislators.

While there's can be *some* overlap between the two categories, neither is a subset of the other, and both have distinct properties.  For example:

- Race usually signifies what are either believed or supposed to be *relatively invariant* properties stemming from necessarily intrinsic or historic commonalities of a fixed grouping.
- Demographics usually refers to *topical and variable* properties of a non-fixed population, without connotations of intrinsic or historic necessity.